# Mysql Multiple Order rows in one table

Tags: mysql

I want to order the rows of the previous year in ascending order , and the rows of the current year in descending order.
Here is my query:

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(DATE) AS WEEK,
YEAR(DATE) YEAR,
COUNT(id) WeekAvg
FROM `user_appoint`
WHERE user_appoint.comp_id=123 
GROUP BY WEEK(DATE) , YEAR(DATE) 
ORDER BY YEAR(DATE) ASC;
```

and the output is :

```
week    Year  WeekAvg  
------  ------  ---------
46    2014          3
47    2014          1
48    2014          6
52    2014          1
12    2015          1
11    2015          1
5    2015          1
```

but my expected output is :

```
week    Year  WeekAvg  
------  ------  ---------
46    2014          3
47    2014          1
48    2014          6
52    2014          1
5    2015          1
11    2015          1
12    2015          1
```

Comment: why descending order? both current and previous year are ordered in ascending order

Comment: and how exactly did the first answer work?

Comment: i wanted the week of the previous year like 46,47,48 and the new year should start with 5,11,12 . In my query it was taking the week as 26,27,28,12,11,5 . with the help of answer now it gives the perfect result. @OzgurBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
SELECT WEEKOFYEAR(DATE) AS WEEK,
YEAR(DATE) YEAR,
COUNT(id) WeekAvg
FROM `user_appoint`
WHERE user_appoint.comp_id=123 
GROUP BY WEEK(DATE) , YEAR(DATE) 
ORDER BY YEAR(DATE) ASC, WEEKOFYEAR(DATE) ASC;
```